# Angular delete button in HttpClient request with Json Server

Tags: javascript, angular

I would like to delete one employee at the time from the list of Employees.The `Observable` is set in the `employee.service.ts` and subscribed in the `app.component.ts`. There are problems to connect to the `id` of the employee with the method `removeUser(id)` in the `app.component.html` and the error is `Property 'id' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.ngtsc(2339)`.

1. I would like to `console.log` the `id` when the relative delete button is clicked but I do not know how.
2. Something like `this.employees = this.employees.filter(employ => employ.id !== id)` is needed to delete the employee, but I am not sure where to insert it.

**employee.service.ts**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { EmployeeInterface } from '../types/employee.interface';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EmployeeService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getUsers(): Observable<EmployeeInterface[]> {
    return this.http.get<EmployeeInterface[]>('http://localhost:3000/employees')
  }

  removeUser(id: string): Observable<{}> {
    return this.http.delete(`http://localhost:3000/employeers/${id}`)
  }

}
```

**app.component.ts**

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { EmployeeService } from './service/employee.service';
import { EmployeeInterface } from './types/employee.interface';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'List of employees';

employees: EmployeeInterface[]=[];

constructor(private employeeService: EmployeeService) {

}

ngOnInit(): void {
this.employeeService.getUsers().subscribe(emp => 
  {
this.employees = emp;
    console.log(this.employees)
  })
  
}

removeUser(id: string): void {
  this.employeeService.removeUser(`http://localhost:3000/users/${id}`).subscribe()
}

}
```

**app.component.html**

```html
{{title}}

<li *ngFor="let employee of employees">{{employee.name}} <button (click)="removeUser(id)">Delete</button></li>
```

**db.json** (used with json server)

```js
{
  "employees": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Tim",
      "hired": true
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Jess",
      "hired": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, there are some problems in your code.

1. In your HTML template, you are not passing the employee ID in the button click output. Because of this you are getting the mentioned error. Your HTML code must be like:

```
<button (click)="removeUser(employee.id)">Delete</button>
```

2. In AppComponent.removeUser, you are passing the complete URL to the service method. You only have to pass the id, like below:

```
removeUser(id: string): void {
   this.employeeService.removeUser(id).subscribe()
}
```

3. You must do the mentioned filter only if the delete request have been successful. For achieve this, your AppComponent.removeUser will be like this:

```
removeUser(id: string): void {
   this.employeeService.removeUser(id)
      .subscribe(() => {
         this.employees = this.employees.filter(employ => employ.id !== id)
      })
}
```

4. To console.log your employee ID, modify again the method:

```
removeUser(id: string): void {
   console.log(`ID of the employee to be removed: ${id}`)
   this.employeeService.removeUser(id)
      .subscribe(() => {
         this.employees = this.employees.filter(employ => employ.id !== id)
      })
}
```

5. Your AppComponent.removeUser can be improved to show a error message to the user if the request fail and a success message too:

```
removeUser(id: string): void {
   console.log(`ID of the employee to be removed: ${id}`)
   this.employeeService.removeUser(id)
      .subscribe({
         next: () => {
            this.employees = this.employees.filter(employ => employ.id !== id)
            console.log(`The employee with ID = ${id} have been removed.`)
            // TODO - Show the success message for the user.
         },
         error: () => {
            console.log(`An error occurred when trying to remove the employee with ID = ${id}.`)
            // TODO - Show the error message for the user.
         }
       })
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your clarity to explain step by step what to do.
Unfortunately it throws error. For instance when button 2 is clicked in console shows: `DELETE http://localhost:3000/employeers/2 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: It shows the other 2 console logs:
-ID of the employee to be removed: 2
-An error occurred when trying to remove the employee with ID = 2.

Comment: I think there is a typo in the request URL, because in your EmployeeService.getUsers you are using "http://localhost:3000/employees", and in EmployeeService.removeUser you are using "http://localhost:3000/employeers". Try changing this "http://localhost:3000/employeers" to "http://localhost:3000/employees" (without the 'r' letter). It solves the problem?

Comment: Well spotted, it works perfectly now. Thank you for that!!!
How can I implement the handling error part (// TODO - Show the error message for the user)? Do you mean like adding a message in the DOM?

Comment: Nice, it's a pleasure to help.
About the message: Exactly. There are many approaches to this: you can use an browser alert; you can add a hidden HTML element and show him setting the display to block; you can use the MatSnackBar from Angular Material.
But this is beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: Thank you for that. It is beyond the scope of this question, yet this very interesting ;)

Now I will try to do add an employee to my App. fingers crossed

Answer (score 0):

It's because on your html file you are calling a function using a variable named 'id', that is supposed to exist in your component file, that's why you are getting that error.

Instead, you need the id of the employee that you are getting at that time from the ngFor, so you need this:

```html
<li *ngFor="let employee of employees">{{employee.name}} <button (click)="removeUser(employee.id)">Delete</button></li>
```

Just like you did with the name of the employee.